# Numbers in SVG cut off, how do I restore them?

Tags: svg

I've been exporting skeletal structures in MarvinSketch to SVGs, sadly sometimes the sides of these files (usually number subscripts) are cut off. For example, see below a PNG export of one such SVG. Note how the NH<sub>2</sub>'s 2 subscript is partially cut off. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_sXH68hMWBTndES0UwZzB1bVE/view?usp=sharing)'s the SVG file used to create this PNG. So my question is how do I make the entire subscript visible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used MarvinSketch and I don't know if you can avoid tis behaviour using some settings, but the cut in your image is due to a [clipping](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip.html) operation (see also [here](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-what-are-clipping-and-masking-in-inkscape--vector-24947)):

[image: text clipped]

To remove the clipping mask, open your SVG file in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org), select your object, in **object** menu choose **clip** and **release**:

[image: clip release]

You see now the black mask (a rectangle) over the drawing, select it:

[image: black mask]

Delete the mask and *voilà*:

[image: the image is free]

Comment: ..or if you don't want to fire up a GUI you can simply delete all of the <clipPath> nodes in the svg itself using your favourite editor/script/intern.

Comment: Yes, is an alternative, but perhaps you need more attention ;-)